# SparkSQL : same query returns different result

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I encountered a weird problem. I wanted to get all data from a dataframe and insert into a permanent hive table and index it to elasticsearch.Query was simple `select * from result*` and I would loop through each row and insert into ES. and simple `insert into <hive_table> select * from result`, but I got different result. So to check I created 3 different temprorary table like this

```
spark.sql("select * from QtyContribution").join(getRevenueContribution(spark,table2), "item").join(finalUniqueItem(spark), "item").registerTempTable("hola");
spark.sql("select * from QtyContribution").join(getRevenueContribution(spark,table2), "item").join(finalUniqueItem(spark), "item").registerTempTable("hola1");
spark.sql("select * from QtyContribution").join(getRevenueContribution(spark,table2), "item").join(finalUniqueItem(spark), "item").registerTempTable("hola2");
```

Each query is same just tables are different. And

```
Dataset<Row> dframe1 = spark.sql("select * from hola");
        Row[] row1 = (Row[]) dframe1.collect();
        int q=1;
        for(Row s : row1){
            System.out.println(s.get(0)+" =======df1======= "+ q++);

        }

Dataset<Row> dframe2 = spark.sql("select * from hola1");
        Row[] row2 = (Row[]) dframe2.collect();
        int w=1;
        for(Row s : row2){
            System.out.println(s.get(0)+" =======df2======= "+ w++);

        }

Dataset<Row> dframe3 = spark.sql("select * from hola2");
        Row[] row3 = (Row[]) dframe3.collect();
        int e=1;
        for(Row s : row2){
            System.out.println(s.get(0)+" =======df3======= "+ e++);

        }
```

And the result I get is this

```
BM8942 =======df1======= 1723
BM8942 =======df2======= 1733
BM8942 =======df3======= 1733
```

And for ES i did

```
Dataset<Row> dframe = spark.sql("select * from hola1");
        Row[] row = (Row[]) dframe.collect();
        int i = 1;
        for (Row r : row) {
        bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("twitter1234", "use1", String.valueOf(i))
                .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                        .startObject()
                        .field("item", r.get(0))
                        .field("qty_contrib", r.get(1))
                        .field("division", r.get(2))
                        .field("rev_contrib", r.get(3))
                        .field("bp", r.get(4))
                        .endObject()
                )
        );
            System.out.println(i++ +" ==== "+r.get(0));
        }
```

and I got

```
1534 ==== BM8942
```

What's happening ?